# IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started on a new Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash

i have an Android App published in the Play Store, and the crashreports show a Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
in

```
public void refresh(){
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mThread) {
        mThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refresh();
            }
        };
        mThread.start();//<<<<<<<<<<<<<here 
        return;
    }
    doSomeCoolStuff();
}
```

how can this happen? it is a new thread?

Metin Kale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen in case of a race condition. Between the two statements (assigning a value to mThread and calling the start() method), the execution can switch to another thread, which can enter the refresh() method again, assign a different thread to mThread, and then start it. When the first thread resumes execution, mThread will contain a different thread (which has already been started), and the start() method will fail with the exception that you describe.

One way to fix this is to store the result of `new Thread()` in a local variable, then call the start() method on that variable, and then save it into the field. (This may not be the most appropriate fix, but it's not possible to say more without knowing more details about the context where the problem happens.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `mThread` is already started and running, thats why do you get that exception.
Try to check the state of `mThread`, and start it only when is in `Thread.State.NEW` state.

```
if (mThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
{
     mThread.start();
}
```

> **Thread.State.NEW**: The thread has been created, but has never been started.